# BING MAPS Drawing a zone based on various coordinates

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing, coordinate-systems

I have a database with the coordinates of the map point, with this information I have to draw circle zones in dependency to the proximity of it, for example if I have four point close for 2 miles it will create a zone and I'll draw the zone in the maps, I need to know the formulas or methods that I need to solve my problem, maybe where I can get the documentation about this kind of coordinates algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. One option is to group all the locations together based on distance into clusters and then use the coordinates of each point in the cluster to create a convex hull. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29275/Convex-Hull

Another approach is to create a voronoi diagram to create your regions. Take a look at this blog post:  http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/nearest-neighbours-voronoi-diagrams-and-finding-your-nearest-sql-server-usergroup/